# Simple php form = too simple to actually work?

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm sitting here wondering wheather this php contact form solution is too simple to actually work. Or, well it does work, but will it always work?

Also, atm when you recieve the email, it says FROM: zsf34o6.mywebsite.com@web09.b-one.com
which means that most mail clients will put it straight in the junkbox. How can I change it to the entered email address?

Thanks!

```
<form method="POST" action="mailer.php">
   <input type="text" name="name" size="19">
   <input type="text" name="phone" size="19">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form> 

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$to = "you@you.com";
$subject = "From website";
$name_field = $_POST['name'];
$phone_field = $_POST['phone'];

$body = "From: $name_field\n E-Mail: $phone_field\n";

echo "Data has been submitted to $to!";
mail($to, $subject, $body);

} else {

echo "Error!";

}
?>
```

Comment: define a header with your own your domain email so it won't be sent as "zsf34o6.mywebsite.com@web09.b-one.com" for example: $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

Comment: what do you mean by "too simple to work?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will work, but your recipient is going to get spammed heavily after it has been out for a while. You can cut back on that a lot by putting another field in the form that is hidden with CSS and then checking that it is still empty before sending your email. As for adjusting the return address, use the forth parameter to the PHP mail function. It will look something like this:

mail($to, $subject, $body, "From:$fromAddress\n");

Here is some quick and dirty code that I have used for a similar form for a website to relay a message to someone's smartphone in a way that makes it easy to give a call back while on the go: 
http://rietta.com/stackoverflow/sample-form.txt

Comment: thats too good!
works perfectly! thanks so much.

just a question: how do the hidden inputs prevent the recipients from getting spammed?

Comment: The idea is that a spambot won't know that the form isn't visible to the user, and will fill it with junk, whereas a real person can't see the form to fill it out.

It's not 100%, but it will cut down a bit.